# How to format a date which is undefined on the first render using the Date API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

While trying to stream on my website with `<audio></audio>` an mp3 from archive.org - which have Partial response (status code 206) - I get:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value
    at Date.toISOString (<anonymous>)
    at setTimes (audio-player.min.js:92:8)
```

I guess it happens because the date to format is undefined on the first render (Partial response).

In fact, to display currentTime and duration properties in real time I'm using:

```
  function setTimes() {
    playerCurrentTime.textContent = new Date(audioElement.currentTime * 1000)
      .toISOString()
      .substr(11, 8);
    playerDuration.textContent = new Date(audioElement.duration * 1000) // Error here "Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value" 
      .toISOString()
      .substr(11, 8);
  }
```

which is causing `Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value`.
There's a way to solve this when the date to format is undefined on the first render, as the mp3 from archive.org is downloaded with partial response?

Comment: A simple solution is console.log **audioElement.duration** and see what it is on load. Then use that in an if statement to not show anything if the passed value is equal to that. So lets assume **audioElement.duration = null** then just do **if(audioElement.duration != null)**

Comment: Good idea. Anyway, in the end, as I already know the duration of each mp3, I decided to pass the data with Nunjucks from a JSON. But I llike you solution and I will keep it for a rainy day. Thanks @imvain2